# Datetime will not update in database

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I can not figure this out. It should be pretty straight forward, but when I add the expiration date variable as seen below nothing is recorded. Not the membership or date. When I remove the date it works fine. What am I doing wrong?

expiration_date in my database is set to timestamp

```
    $uid    = $_SESSION['userId'];
    $uemail = $_SESSION['usersEmail'];
    $uname  = $_SESSION['usersName'];

    $membership = 'Basic';
    $expiration = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE users 
    SET 
    membership = ?,
    expiration_date = ? 

    WHERE usersEmail = '".$uemail."'"); 

$stmt->bind_param('s,s', $membership, $expiration);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
```

Comment: Are you sure you need a comma in between `s,s` in bindParam ?

Comment: that was embarrassingly simple, thank you @AbhikChakraborty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your bind_param must be:

```
$stmt->bind_param("ss",$membership, $expiration);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Pointed out by Abhik Chakraborty in the comments section.